# how to loop through an array and know what values ​are repeated

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I have this array

```
array = [{
product:product1,
price: 2000
},
{
product:product2,
price: 3000
},
{
product:product1,
price: 450
},
{
product:product2,
price: 3400
}]
```

I would like to know how I could go through this array, ask if there are attributes that are repeated,
the first thing I have to obtain is the minimum price among the products that are repeated, for example of the products1 the minimum price between them would be 450, and of the products2 the minimum would be 3000, the same with de maximum price, then I have to add those minimums and maximums and put them into a variable called minimumTotal and total maximum.
The idea is to get something like this:

```
array = [{
product:product1,
price: 2000
},
{
product:product2,
price: 3000
},
{
product:product1,
price: 450
},
{
product:product2,
price: 3400
},
minimumTotal:3450,
maximumTotal:5400
]
```

Someone help me please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm to solve your problem can vary a lot.

I would say you must, first, understand how to break the problem in multiple little problems. Then, you can solve them as possible.

For instance, you can combine the following two steps to get the job almost done:

- transforms the initial array in the following data structure

```
const reducedValues = [
  {
    "product": "product1",
    "values": [450, 2000],
  },
  {
    "product": "product2",
    "values": [3000, 3400],
  },
];
```

- gets the min and max values:

```
const minValues = [450, 3000];
const maxValues = [2000, 3400];
```

I did not show you how to do your job, but this is clearly a great help.

---

**Tip**: you can use the `.reduce()` function.

For further info, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce.